# Css ID with Class - Parent Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

The Html is:

Parent:

div id="sticky-header-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 149px;"

Child:

nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix" role="navigation" aria-label="Main Menu"

I am trying to hide site-navigation. What is the correct way to select the property here. I have tried:

#sticky-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper is-sticky #site-navigation {display:none;}

Comment: #site-navigation {display:none;} as is doesn't do it? I thought that's all it would take.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple classes for the same node that you want to target, you must use the dot-notation for each class, e.g. `.class1.class2 { ... }`.

You can do something like the following for your usecase:

```css
#sticky-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky #site-navigation {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky-header-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 149px;">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix" role="navigation" aria-label="Main Menu">NAV</nav>
  <div>NOT NAV</div>
</div>
```

But an alternative approach to this is to simply target the `id` since that is supposed to be unique (not always adhered to be developers).

In that case, this would work the same:

```
#site-navigation {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#sticky-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky #site-navigation {
  display:none;
}
```

Don't do this as this will make the selector specificity too big and so if you need to override it later, you will need to come up with a selector that has an even bigger specificity.

I'd recommend just use a class selector like so:

```css
.main-navigation: {
  display:none;
}
```

This way, the selector is easier to read and has less css specificity which means that you can override it very easily with another class selector.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is unique, you can for sure do it like :

```
div.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky #site-navigation{
  display:none;
}
```

or

```
div#sticky-header-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper.is-sticky #site-navigation {
     display:none;
}
```

But the best and simplest approach is

```
#site-navigation{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a "." before (is-sticky) class.